# How to conditionally change colnames from certain rows?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a problem that arises often working with excel survey data: the first 10 or so column names are appropriate in a data set, the remaining `x:ncol` need to be renamed to the values of first row of the data set, starting at x+1. (The colnames are correct until x, after which point the colnames become empty, with the values that I would like to have as the colname being in the first row).

I have been doing this manually, writing them out one by one using `dplyr::select()`. How can I automate this in a tidy workflow? I imagine using `set_names()` or `rename_at()` but can't get the syntax. Thank you in advance

```
mtcars %>% 
select(miles_per_gallon = "mpg", everything()) %>% #etc. keep some names
rename_at(vars(3:ncol(.)), funs(mtcars[,1]))


Error: `nm` must be `NULL` or a character vector the same length as `x`
```

The error isn't surprising, but to illustrate the point - how to have the names from x:ncol() replaced by the first row's values starting from x+1?

Comment: I didn't get this "the remaining `x:ncol` need to be renamed to the first row of the data set, starting at `x+1`". Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Shree does my edit answer your question?

Comment: I think I understand. See my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you, yes it did. the need to a) reference DF inside ncol() and outside the subset was my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it for you -

```
x <- 10 # means 1:10 column names are appropriate

names(df)[(x+1):ncol(df)] <- df[1, (x+1):ncol(df)]

df <- df[-1, ] # removing 1st row assuming it's bad data
```